# Pandas groupby agg with multiple functions to apply returns error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by, aggregate

**Problem** Attempting a groupby on a simple [dataframe](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6ymLohJIbhCQzNEdDdTaFVHSU0) (downloadable csv) and then agg to return aggregate values for columns (size, sum, mean, std deviation). What seems like a simple problem is giving an unexpectedly challenging error.

```
Top15.groupby('Continent')['Pop Est'].agg(np.mean, np.std...etc)
# returns 
ValueError: No axis named <function std at 0x7f16841512f0> for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

What I am trying to get is a df with index set to continents and columns `['size', 'sum', 'mean', 'std']`

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create df
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country':['Australia','China','America','Germany'],'Pop Est':['123','234','345','456'],'Continent':['Asia','Asia','North America','Europe']})

# group and agg
df = df.groupby('Continent')['Pop Est'].agg('size','sum','np.mean','np.std')
```

Comment: The syntax is `agg([np.mean, np.std, ...])`.

Comment: @IgorRaush I've tried that and get a `DataError: No numeric types to aggregate`, which is weird b/c when I look at the dataframe, it's clear there's data.

Comment: Your example data has the 'Pop Est' column as strings, not numeric data, which is why you're getting the error.  Try `df['Pop Est'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Pop Est'])` or `df['Pop Est'] = df['Pop Est'].astype(int)` before performing the `groupby`, using the syntax mentioned by Igor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only aggregate size and sum on numeric values so when you create your dataframe don't input your numbers as stings:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country':['Australia','China','America','Germany'],'PopEst':[123,234,345,456],'Continent':['Asia','Asia','North America','Europe']})
```

I think that this will get you what you want?

```
grouped = df.groupby('Continent')
grouped['PopEst'].agg(['size','sum','mean','std'])


size    sum mean    std
Continent               
Asia    2   357 178.5   78.488853
Europe  1   456 456.0   NaN
North America   1   345 345.0   NaN
```

Comment: When I use your syntax, I still get a DataError: No numeric types to aggregate. However, when I just use the 'size' method, things work fine. I've confirmed that the Pop Est column in my original data set is type float. Interestingly, I found success by converting the Pop Est column with .astype(np.float64) and then using your syntax.

Comment: I think that's because you're using 'np.sum' instead of "sum"?

Comment: I have a question here: when I use this line.

grouped['PopEst'].agg(['size','sum','mean','std'])

How do pandas know that I want size(), sum(), etc..

Are those strings ['size','sum','mean','std'] mapped to calculating these aggregate functions? Are they standard?

Comment: Yes, those functions are built into groupby function. Here is the list of possibilities: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/groupby.html